# How to deploy Azure SQL DB with SQL Tables using ARM?

Tags: azure

I have this requirement using Azure ARM template which I need to create tables while deploying the Azure ARM Template to create Azure SQL DB. I have followed the following tutorial - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2016/03/28/deploy-bacpac-to-azure-sql-database-using-arm/

But this did not work - do anyone knows how can I do this?

Comment: what are the errors? i recall it was working for me just fine

Comment: according to this tutorial when I deploy the .bacpac file it does not upload and executed and there is notable in the Azure SQL DB - no errors either :(

Comment: show your code? how are you "uploading it"?

Comment: I can give you my VS Solution - [here you can download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zcmiBhZhn9zdydJ1c0HXeahLXpblCtBZ/view?usp=sharing"). According to the tutorial, it should be automatically uploaded right ? but mine it does not happen

Comment: it should do that if you give it the `-UploadArtifacts` switch, without it it wouldn't upload anything. its quite clear looking at the script in the solution you provided

Comment: Now I tried with that and the .bacpac file was uploaded but I can't see the tables in the database.

Comment: This is the error I get in the Package Manage Console - [Click for the link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZlhH3gehmfnTBdb2237BAO5M6CqGBan0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: looks like sas is wrong. did you alter the script in anyway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196501/discussion-between-dileepa-and-4c74356b41).

Comment: I didn't change anything in the PS script but changed the JSON template as given in the tutorial

Comment: just generate SAS token manually and use that to deploy the template or use public level access for blobs, that way you dont need SAS at all